# Strange bug in windows when running code in c

Tags: c, windows

I have written some code to solve the british informatics olympiad question 1 (2012) in c. If it is of any help to anyone, or possibly of interest, the program finds the product of the unique prime factors of a number. If the number is prime, it returns the original number.

It is supposed to work up to an input of 1 000 000 and it does so when compiled on linux and mac.

For some reason when it is compiled on windows (using the mingw compiler) it does not work for an input above 520558!

It is probably something to do with the declaration of an array that is 520558 integers long but I have no idea how to remedy it.

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    printf("Please enter your input: ");
    int input;
    scanf("%d",&input);
    int numbers[input-2];
    for (int i=0;i<input-2;i++) {
        numbers[i] = i+2;
    }
    for (int i=0;i<input-2;i++) {
        if(numbers[i] == 0) {
            continue;
        }else{
            for (int j=(i+2)*2;j<input;j+=numbers[i]){
                numbers[j-2] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    int product = 1;
    for (int i=0;i<input-2;i++) {
        if(numbers[i]!=0){
            if(input%numbers[i]==0) {
                product *= numbers[i];
            }
        }
    }
    if(product == 1){
        printf("%u",input); 
    }else{
        printf("%u",product);
    }
    printf("\n");
    // Get rid of this on mac and linuxs
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can't find a block (on stack) larger than ~2 megabytes? - `int numbers[input-2];` idk??

Comment: I don't think you can dynamically allocate an array like that.

Comment: "it doesn't work" refers to the program crashing.
You must be able to allocate such a large array because it works on linux and mac. While I understand that there is a difference in the way that the operating systems work, I would have thought that there would be a way to either fix this or get around it.

By the way, thank you very much for the prompt replies!

Comment: C99 variable length arrays suck. There is no way to detect (or recover from) an error. Repeat after me: **VLAs suck!!** (especially large(ish) ones).

Comment: Managed to get it myself (I did it the same way as is shown below) Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int numbers[input-2];`

This creates an integer array on the stack. The stack has a limited size; this is typically a power of two on the order of a couple of megabytes or less. 520558 is suspiciously close to 2^19, suggesting a 2Mb stack area.

If you are dealing with arrays this large, you should use the heap instead:

```
int * numbers = (int*)malloc((input-2)*sizeof(int)); 
. 
. 
. 
free(numbers); 
return 0;
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I actually managed to get this myself after you posted the C++ code and the suggestion of using the heap instead of using the stack.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing your `numbers` declaration with this:

```
int* numbers = (int *) malloc((input-2)*sizeof(int));
```

As squiguy mentioned, this will dynamically allocate the array on the heap, avoiding any potential stack problems you may have. You should also free it when it is done, with:

```
free(numbers);
```

Comment: This dynamically allocates enough space on the heap.  You might add that it is good practice to free(numbers) after it is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to allocate the `numbers` variable on the heap instead of stack:

```
#define MAXNUMS 1000000
int numbers[MAXNUMS];

int main() {
...
}
```

Comment: That would allocate it on the stack.

Comment: @squiguy: I edited the answer for clarity. Thanks for the review.